# How to preventDefault() in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a timer and I have set the following as default values in data:

```
data: () => {
  return {
    hour: 0;
    min: 0;
    sec: 0;
  }
}
```

Then I have set the following function to trigger the timer:

```
methods: {
  startTimer: function () {
      var self = this;
      if (self.hour !== 0 && self.min !== 0 && self.sec !== 0) {
        preventDefault();
      } else {
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
          self.totalSeconds += 1;

          self.hour = Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 3600);
          self.min = Math.floor((self.totalSeconds / 60) % 60);
          self.sec = parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60);
        }, 1000);
      }
    },
}
```

Now, whenever I trigger the timer with a button `<div @click="startTimer()">add timer</div>` by spamming it, the seconds would jump very fast as if two or three timers running concurrently (which I think it is). I want to set preventDefault() but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to turn off the button if the hour, mins and seconds are all = 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get the click event from the method :

```
methods: {
  startTimer: function (event) {
      var self = this;
      if (self.hour !== 0 && self.min !== 0 && self.sec !== 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
      } else {
 ...
```

and you shouldn't use the `()` in the template in order to get the event passed as parameter :

```
<div @click="startTimer">add timer</div
```

or pass `$event` as parameter :

```
<div @click="startTimer($event)">add timer</div
```

Comment: It doesn't work with "event.preventDefault();" I have used the () in the template because I have to execute 2 functions within the v-bind click - apparently it wouldn't work if I don't include () within the template. The only solution I have is to set the state as true and toggle the button with v-if by changing it to false after pressing the button, but that doesn't seem like a solution, more like a work around.

Comment: Try out `@click="startTimer($event)"`

Comment: Actually it worked now with ($event) after I have reloaded localhost. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

call the function without the parenthesis `()`

```vuejs
<div @click="startTimer">add timer</div
```

And then in the startTime function the event will automatically be injected by vuejs which you can use to preventDefault.

```vuejs
methods: {
  startTimer: function (event) {
      var self = this;
      if (self.hour !== 0 && self.min !== 0 && self.sec !== 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
      } else {
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
          self.totalSeconds += 1;

          self.hour = Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 3600);
          self.min = Math.floor((self.totalSeconds / 60) % 60);
          self.sec = parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60);
        }, 1000);
      }
    },
}
```

[More information](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have followed @Boussadjra's suggestion on adding @click="startTimer($event) and it worked.

Comment: Actually, as per the documentation there's absolutely no need to do it manually. Event should always be injected by vuejs. Please have a look at the documentation on best practices, as I'm sure that approach will cause issue for you in future. Nevertheless, you are free to use the approach you are comfortable with. Thanks